# How to download attachment on email using php

Tags: php

I have tried to save attachment but i couldn't download attachment with this code .it create a folder for downloading file. any one? How to save a attachment on email in php? 
thanks in advance

```
  $struct = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$msgno);
  $contentParts = count($struct->parts);
  if ($contentParts >= 2) 
  {
     for ($i=2;$i<=$contentParts;$i++) 
     {
          $att[$i-2] = imap_bodystruct($mbox,$msgno,$i); 
     }
     for ($k=0;$k<count($att);$k++) 
     {
         if ($att[$k]->parameters[0]->value == "us-ascii" || $att[$k]->parameters[0]->value    == "US-ASCII") 
       {
                if ($att[$k]->parameters[1]->value != "") 
            {
                     $selectBoxDisplay[$k] = $att[$k]->parameters[1]->value;
                }
         } 
       elseif ($att[$k]->parameters[0]->value != "iso-8859-1" &&    $att[$k]->parameters[0]->value != "ISO-8859-1") 
       {
              $selectBoxDisplay[$k] = $att[$k]->parameters[0]->value;
         }
     }
  }
  //print_r($att); 
  if (count($selectBoxDisplay) > 0) 
  {
      for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($selectBoxDisplay);$j++) 
      {
            $strFileName = $att[$j]->parameters[0]->value;
        $strFileType = strrev(substr(strrev($strFileName),0,4));
        $fileContent = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$msgno,$j+2);
        $ret = downloadFile($strFileType,$strFileName,$fileContent);
        $selectBoxDisplay[$j] = str_replace($search,'',$selectBoxDisplay[$j]);                 
        $filenametmp = $selectBoxDisplay[$j];   
        $handle = fopen($filenametmp, "w+");
        fwrite($handle, $ret);
        fclose($handle);    
        //chmod($filenametmp, 777);       
        }            
  }
```

Comment: Handling IMAP / POP3 is cumbersome with PHP. I have already been through hell trying to ensure that I could read messages, including attachments, inline-attachments and more. Checkout this class I made for using IMAP, it makes life alot easier: https://github.com/EJTH/php-mailbox-reader ... I am pretty sure that there is other solutions just search for it.